# Name attribute is obsolete, what is the correct behavior when dealing with anchors?

Tags: html5, markup, anchor, w3c-validation

When testing my code using the [w3 html5 validator](https://validator.w3.org/), I get this warning message:

> **Warning**: The `name` attribute is obsolete. Consider putting an `id` attribute on the nearest container instead.

*Question(s):*

- *What does the nearest container mean?*
- *Is empty `<a>` now deprecated?*
- *Should I use `id` instead of `name`?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [A]re empty placeholder  tags as a
>   whole deprecated, and anchors can
>   simply point to any element with an id
>   instead?

I prefer to jump users to heading tags (following MediaWiki's default behavior) where in-page links are needed, but yes, you could address the ID of any element.

Answer (score 21):

If you need to jump users to in-page links, also known as **fragment identifiers**, you can set the `id` attribute (which is [used for more than just frag ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001236/why-should-one-add-id-to-their-html-tags/13001519#13001519)) on *any* element. Then use the usual `#` in the URL of a `href` attribute of an `a` element. Here’s an example:

```
<body>
  <p>Despite the many
    <a href="#benefits-of-gum-chewing">benefits</a>
    you may experience while chewing gum, there are also many drawbacks,
    especially with 
    <a href="http://www.example.org/sugar.html#cons">non-sugarless</a>
    gum.</p>
  ...
  <section id="benefits-of-gum-chewing">
    <h1>Benefits of Gum Chewing</h1>
    ...
  </section>
</body>
```

When writing my own pages, I like to give an `id` to each `<section>` tag (HTML5), even if I don’t plan on using it. The value of the `id` is a URL-friendly version of its heading’s content. You can achieve the same effect by assigning the same `id` to an `<h1>`, etc.

Lastly, empty `<a>` tags are not deprecated, as indicated in [the HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> If the `a` element has no `href` attribute, then the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed …

Additionally the same applies for [`area` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#links-created-by-a-and-area-elements):

> The `href` attribute on `a` and `area` elements is not required; when those elements do not have `href` attributes they do not create hyperlinks.

Answer (score 3):

For HTML5, `name` attribute is now deprecated, so that means to use `id` in place of `name`. Otherwise, everything else is the same.

`<a>` is NOT deprecated.

Comment: While this answer is good, a link to documentation or an article explaining the deprecation would make it even better.

Comment: Specifically, it is the `name` attribute on the _anchor_ element that is deprecated/obsolete. The `name` attribute is still perfectly valid (and required) on other elements.